# Entropy bounds and the size of the universe

Tags: cosmology, entropy, holographic-principle

The principle that the maximum amount of information or entropy a volume of space can hold is proportional to its surface area apparently applies to all space, not just black holes. Since volume grows asymptotically faster than surface area and there there is also a limit on the information per surface area this should imply limits on the possible size, shape and density of the universe.  To what extent have these limits been worked out?